# Isabelle: How can I identify two ancestor locales with equal but not identical parameters?

Tags: isabelle

I have a locale structure where a certain locale appears two times as an ancestor of another locale, one time through inheritance and another time through a sequence of several `sublocale` interpretations. The parameters of the two instances of that ancestor locale are equal but not identical (their equality has to be and can be established by a proof). How can I make Isabelle collapse these two ancestor locale instances into one, as it would do when the parameters were identical?

The following minimal example demonstrates my situation:

```
theory Diamond
  imports Main
begin

typedecl a
typedecl b
typedecl c

consts a_from_b :: "b ⇒ a"
consts b_from_a_and_c :: "[a, c] ⇒ b"

lemma equality: "a_from_b (b_from_a_and_c a c) = a"
  sorry

locale a =
  fixes a :: a

locale b =
  fixes b :: b
begin

sublocale a "a_from_b b" .

end

locale c = a +
  fixes c :: c
begin

sublocale b "b_from_a_and_c a c" .

end

end
```

The command `print_dependencies! c` yields the following output:

```
dependencies:
  a "a"
  a "a_from_b (b_from_a_and_c a c)"
  b "b_from_a_and_c a c"
  c "a" "c"
```

Clearly there are two instances of `a`. How can I make use of the lemma mentioned in the above piece of code to turn theses two locale instances into a single instance `a "a"`? I’ve tried to achieve that by changing the `sublocale` interpretation inside the `locale c` declaration to the following:

```
sublocale b "b_from_a_and_c a c" rewrites "a = a_from_b (b_from_a_and_c a c)"
  by (simp add: equality)
```

However, this causes Isabelle to hang.

Answer (score 0):

The idea mentioned at the very end of the question almost works. It’s just that the sides of the `rewrite` equation have to be swapped:

```
sublocale b "b_from_a_and_c a c" rewrites "a_from_b (b_from_a_and_c a c) = a"
  by (fact equality)
```

With this change in place, `print_dependencies! c` yields the following output:

```
dependencies:
  a "a"
  b "b_from_a_and_c a c"
  c "a" "c"
```